# Cypress 10 method stub does not work in e2e test

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, stub, react-18

I have react18 (typescript) app and want to test it with cypress 10.
I wrote e2e cypress, and for some reason I have to stub one method - regular method, not network call.
the method I want to stub:

```
export class UserUtil {
    public async init() {
        ...
    }
}

const userUtil = new UserUtil();
export default userUtil;
```

I'm trying to stub it beforeEach test:

```
import userUtil from '../../../userUtil';

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.stub(userUtil, 'init').as('init');
  cy.visit('/');
}
```

I can see the stub in the stub list:

[image]

but actually it has no calls. in dev tools I can see the original code is called.

I tried to stub different type of methods (static, arrow functions) and nothing worked.
maybe I can't do it on e2e tests this way?
(I have component test with stubbing and it works well)

Comment: Oddly enough, having the exact same issue today. Tried all manner of things with no luck

Comment: I assume the code of stubbing and the application code are running in different context. I found workaround, intercept the request for bundle.js and changing the body, based on this module: https://github.com/bahmutov/mock-in-bundle (I investigated the code and wrote my own method of stubbing)

Comment: That's smart, but sadly not working with production code which rules it out for me.